# Angular fileReplacements does not work with assets after upgrading

Tags: angular, ng-build, angular.json

After upgrading angular, fileReplacements is not working anymore with assets, here is my code :

```
  "fileReplacements": [
       {
         "replace": "src/assets/scss/x.scss",
         "with": "src/assets/scss/app.scss"
       },
    ]
```

and i tried this

```
"assets": [
 {
    "input": "src/assets/scss/x",
    "output": "assets/scss/",
   "glob": "app.scss"
 },
]
```

how to resolve this and can replace my file while building the project with specefic configuration

Comment: That's because you must follow the pattern `\.(([cm]?j|t)sx?|json)$`. The compiler should give you an error in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your response, yes that's the problem but what i'm asking is if is there another method/option to do this and replace some scss file before the final build

Comment: Yes, you can. I'll post an answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it using `fileReplacements` but you can achieve it in this way.

First, in your `angular.json` file, you can use `stylePreprocessorOptions` this way:

```
{
    "production": {
        "fileReplacements": [
            {
                "replace": "foo",
                "with": "bar"
            }
        ],
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
            "includePaths": [
                "src/assets/styles/folderForProduction/"
            ]
        },
        "outputHashing": "all"
    },
    "development": {
        "buildOptimizer": false,
        "optimization": false,
        "vendorChunk": true,
        "extractLicenses": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "namedChunks": true,
        "fileReplacements": [
            {
                "replace": "foo",
                "with": "baz"
            }
        ],
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
            "includePaths": [
                "src/assets/styles/folderForDevelop/"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you can create two files for an example in `src/assets/styles/folderForProduction/` and in `src/assets/styles/folderForDevelop` and put something like:

```
html,
body {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: red;
}
```

in both of them. For develop change the `color` to be blue instead.

now you can run your application both ways:

`ng serve --configuration development` and you will see the color blue.

`ng serve --configuration production` and you will see the color red.